# Java c++ native functions registered with a delay

Tags: android, qt, java-native-interface

I have the following code for my activity:

```
class MyJavaNatives
{
    public static native void onNewDownload(String url);
}


public class MyActivity extends QtActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.processIntent(getIntent());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        this.processIntent(intent);
    }


    protected void processIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent != null)
        {
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            if (data != null)
                MyJavaNatives.onNewDownload(data.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

If my app is running already - works fine. I.e. `MyJavaNatives.onNewDownload` is defined and called ok from `onNewIntent` method. But if I start my app with some intent, it crashes. Logcat says No implementation found:

```
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.freedownloadmanager.fdm.MyJavaNatives.onNewDownload(java.lang.String) (tried Java_org_freedownloadmanager_fdm_MyJavaNatives_onNewDownload and Java_org_freedownloadmanager_fdm_MyJavaNatives_onNewDownload__Ljava_lang_String_2)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at org.freedownloadmanager.fdm.MyJavaNatives.onNewDownload(Native Method)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at org.freedownloadmanager.fdm.MyActivity.processIntent(MyActivity.java:35)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at org.freedownloadmanager.fdm.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:20)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
08-22 11:10:02.087  7630  7630 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
08-22 11:10:02.110  1684  2764 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity org.freedownloadmanager.fdm/.MyActivity
```

I've tried both methods of registering my c++ function (described here: https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-5/).

Is it Qt bug or Android NDK bug? I use the suggested r10e version of NDK.

Comment: For now, I use timer based workaround.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70114